# Difference Between getcwd() and dirname(__FILE__) ? Which should I use?

Tags: directory, php

In PHP what is the difference between

```
getcwd()
dirname(__FILE__)
```

They both return the same result when I echo from CLI

```
echo getcwd()."\n";
echo dirname(__FILE__)."\n";
```

Returns:

```
/home/user/Desktop/testing/
/home/user/Desktop/testing/
```

Which is the best one to use? Does it matter? What to the more advanced PHP developers prefer?

Comment: Don't forget that `dirname(__FILE__)` is same as  `__DIR__`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`__FILE__` is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) containing the full path to the file you are executing. If you are inside an include, its path will be the contents of `__FILE__`.

So with this setup:

**/folder/random/foo.php**

```
<?php
echo getcwd() . "\n";
echo dirname(__FILE__) . "\n" ;
echo "-------\n";
include 'bar/bar.php';
```

**/folder/random/bar/bar.php**

```
<?php
echo getcwd() . "\n";
echo dirname(__FILE__) . "\n";
```

You get this output:

```
/folder/random
/folder/random
-------
/folder/random
/folder/random/bar
```

So `getcwd()` returns the directory where you started executing, while `dirname(__FILE__)` is file-dependent.

On my webserver, `getcwd()` returns the location of the file that originally started executing. Using the CLI it is equal to what you would get if you executed `pwd`. This is supported by the [documentation of the CLI SAPI](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php) and a comment on the `getcwd` manual page:

> the CLI SAPI does - contrary to other SAPIs - NOT automatically change the current working directory to the one the started script resides in.

So like:

```
thom@griffin /home/thom $ echo "<?php echo getcwd() . '\n' ?>" >> test.php
thom@griffin /home/thom $ php test.php 
/home/thom
thom@griffin /home/thom $ cd ..
thom@griffin /home $ php thom/test.php 
/home
```

Of course, see also the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

**UPDATE**: Since PHP 5.3.0 you can also use the magic constant `__DIR__` which is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Perfect example is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a quick way to get the directory of the main script from the included script. So inside an included script which will be in a different directory, I want to know the directory of the main script that includes it.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I don't know if there's a better way, but you could try setting a constant in the main file to the value of `__DIR__`.

Comment: @ThomWiggers, Seems like `__DIR__` is more performant is that right?

Comment: I have no idea how they work internally, so I don't know. I doubt it matters much though and you should probably make that choice based on functionality.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try this.</strike>

Move your file into another directory say `testing2`.

This should be the result.

```
/home/user/Desktop/testing/
/home/user/Desktop/testing/testing2/
```

I would think `getcwd` is used for file operations, where `dirname(__FILE__)` uses the magic constant `__FILE__` and uses the actual file path.

---

Edit: I was wrong.

Well you can change the working directory, with `chdir`.

So if you do that...

```
chdir('something');
echo getcwd()."\n";
echo dirname(__FILE__)."\n";
```

Those should be different.

Comment: Nope, this time it just echos /home/user/Desktop/testing/testing2 twice

Comment: OK, so let me be sure I got this...

dirname(__FILE__) will *always* produce the location of the file in use. While getcwd will return the current working dir for the PHP process running (such as my command line script.)

So assuming this, if I use a include("path/to/some/file/from/chdir/"); it should be able to find the referenced file?

Answer (score 1):

If you call the file from the command line, the difference is clear.

```
cd foo
php bin/test.php
```

within test.php, `getcwd()` would return `foo` (your current working directory) and `dirname(__FILE__)` would return `bin` (the dirname of the file executing).