# How do I include a PHP script from a base path other than the current script?

Tags: php, include, directory

I have a PHP application I'm trying to include, but it's causing problems because I'm trying to include its files from a subdirectory. For instance, here's the directory structure (more or less) I'm trying to work with:

```
/site
    /scripts
        /local
            some_script.php
    lib_file_a.php
    lib_file_b.php
    lib_load.php
```

`lib_load.php` has an `include` command for files `lib_file_a.php` and `lib_file_b.php` (relative path).

What I want to accomplish is to include `lib_load.php` from `some_script.php`, but there's a problem with the way I'm including `lib_load.php`. At first I tried `require('../../../lib_load.php');`.

As you would expect I saw the error, "Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\site\scripts\local\lib_file_a.php'". As you can see, PHP is trying to include a file that does not exist. I found a Stack Overflow post that told me about using an absolute path [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code), but this did not help. I next tried this code:

```
require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../' . 'lib_load.php'));
```

However, this time, the same error comes back. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I realized that the issue was actually in the library loader, which turned out to be including files based on an absolute path, not a relative path. (I should have read more carefully.) I resolved the issue by changing the path used by the library. This question should be closed if a mod sees this request.

Answer (score 9):

To include lib load

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/scripts/lib_load.php';
```

inside of lib load

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib_file_a.php';
```

if I got your problem  right

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../lib_load.php');
```

Or if you're using PHP 5.3 or higher use this instead (it looks nicer):

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../../lib_load.php');
```