# Warning with, fopen, feof and fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fgetcsv, feof

I'm in trouble, I am failing to understand why this error is happening.

So when I only run this code,

```
function getClientProject($cliente)
{
    $file = fopen("Projetos.csv","r");
    $ArrayCount = 0;
    $bool = false;
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        $data = fgetcsv($file);
        if($data[0] != '')
        {
            if(substr_compare($data[0],$cliente, 0, 3) == 0)
            {
                if($ArrayCount > 0)
                {
                    $total = count($OpenProject);
                    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
                    {
                        if($OpenProject[$i] == $data[0])
                            $bool = true;
                    }
                    if($bool == false)
                    {
                        $OpenProject[$ArrayCount] = $data[0];
                        $ArrayCount++;
                    }
                }else
                {
                    $OpenProject[$ArrayCount] = $data[0];
                    $ArrayCount++;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $OpenProject;
}
```

It works and returns the Array. But when I call the function this way,

```
include_once 'CRM files/TSread.php';
$arrayC = getClientProject('SLA');

var_dump($arrayC);
```

No longer works and me these errors,

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

path, the file i'm using is "Projeto.php":

[image]

and my CRM files folder:
[image]

Comment: Where is `Projetos.csv` ? I mean the path. Ans also the script path.

Comment: TSread.php (php file that contains getClientProject ) and the Projetos.csv are in the same folder

Comment: File paths are relative to the main PHP file, not the file that contains the `fopen` etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file using a relative path. You assume that `Projetos.csv` is always in the same directory as the `TSread.php` file. Although, when including it, you seem to be in a higher directory (outside of the CRM files directory), therefor PHP can no longer find your CSV file, since it's trying to open it relative to the upper directory now.

You could pass the full path to your `getClientProject` method to avoid this. So, you would get something like:

```
$arrayC = getClientProject('SLA', __DIR__ . '/CRM files/Projectos.csv');
```

Obviously, you will need to change your function a little to work with this new constructor, so it should like something like this:

```
function getClientProject($cliente, $csv) {
    $file = fopen($csv, "r");
    // Followed by the rest of your function
```