# PHP Include doesnt work in Sub Directories?

Tags: php, html, css

```
Root
/index.php ----//The homepage, including head.php works fine
/s/affiliate.php ----//A sub page, will not load the head.php
/structure/head.php
```

So the above is how its set out. I am trying to include head in pages across my website. I have hundreds of pages. It works fine on the index.php using

```
<?php include "structure/head.php"; ?>
```

However on any sub pages, it just doesnt load. I guess its the way it searches through directories but I have also tried to make it search from root and it still isnt working, any ideas?

```
 <?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/structure/head.php' ); ?>
```

Comment: Show your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value

Comment: Just for future this called debugging. You might start with simple things like `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/structure/head.php')` And work your way up to xdebug or something. Very useful skill ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)

Comment: Do you want to **always include the file relative to the current PHP script**? If so the just do: `include __DIR__ .'/'. "structure/head.php";` It will always include that file that is in the same directory as the script. If it was in the parent directory then include a relative directory path. i.e.  `include __DIR__ .'/../'. "structure/head.php";` etc.

Answer (score 1):

use relative paths:

```
include("../structure/head.php");
```

Comment: Was hoping there was a simpler way of doing it which could remain the same across all pages

Comment: If your subpage was a controller action invoked from your index using a router and loading a template with the include inside, then all paths would be relative to index. But architecture is off-topic.

Comment: may I suggest that _absolute paths are always used_ i.e. `include(__DIR__ .'/'. "../structure/head.php");` That way, as the `current working directory' is never used then the file that is relative to the current script will always be included. i.e imo,  never use relative paths in PHP scripts. _Always use absolute paths with a relative directory as part of the path_.

Comment: @RyanVincent I agree with absolute paths, but `__DIR__.'/'."../"` is not an absolute path. It's a realive path using the current directory of the file as base and not the current working directory of php (which may vary)

Comment: No, it is an absolute path - **it does not use the Curremt Working Directory**! It has relative directories in it. **It is still an absolute path  according to the operating system**. This is not a PHP thing. This is an O/S thing. `__DIR__` is **always the full path to this PHP script**!

Comment: I can provide code that shows this if you want? Look-  check the [realpath — Returns canonicalized absolute pathname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php). Try it in scripts and change the `CWD` with `chdir` -. Using relative paths - it returns different results. Using absolute paths with relative directories it returns the paths that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT,

**EDIT**

This should work

```
$protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '' ? 'http://' : 'https://';
$web_root = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
define('WEB_ROOT', $web_root);

include (WEB_ROOT.'/file.php');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work
<?php include( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'structure/head.php' ); ?>

Comment: Besides __DIR__ i think the best option is to create a config file and define your absolute path there. 
You can use this absolute path whenever you want later

$protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '' ? 'http://' : 'https://';
$web_root= $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
define('WEB_ROOT', $web_root)

Answer (score 0):

Use include("../path/to/head.php");
This should work since it will be able to direct your code to the sub directory where you have stored your head.php