# Use my autoloader everywhere?

Tags: php, pdo, autoloader

> I have an autoloader which loads all the classes I need

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('app_autoload');

function app_autoload($class)
{
    require "class/$class.php";
}
?>
```

But there is a problem, if I create a login folder and I need to use my autoloader inside this folder, the autoloader still do a `**require "class/$class.php";**` but the folder has changed and should be `**../class/$class.php**`

How can I manage my code for it to be available in every folders of my website ?

Thanks

Comment: Use an absolute path to the class directory. You could use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or a constant defined elsewhere or even just add the class directory to the list of include paths.

Comment: Related (on the fence about a dupe) : [Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't rely on composer's autoloader?