# php how to relative pathing

Tags: php, relative-path

How to do relative pathing? how to use `__dir__`

here is my file structure before

```
public_html
  ├── config
  |    |__config.php
  ├── core
  |    |__init.php
  ├── helper
  |    |__helper.php
  ├── libraries
  |    |__page1.php
  ├── templates
  │   ├── page1template.php
  │
  │__index.php
  │__page1.php
```

After having too many pages. I want to tiddy them up into "rep" folder and "admin" folder. so my new file structure look like this

```
public_html
  ├── config
  |    |__config.php
  ├── core
  |    |__init.php
  ├── helper
  |    |__helper.php
  ├── libraries
  |    |__page1.php
  ├── templates
  │   ├── page1template.php
  │
  │__index.php
  |
  ├── rep
  |    |__page1.php
  ├── admin
  │   ├── page1.php
```

The problem is, my requires and includes are still absolute pathing. see a sample below

my init file

```
//Start Session
session_start();

//Include Configuration
require_once('config/config.php');

//Helper Function Files
require_once('helpers/system_helper.php');
require_once('helpers/format_helper.php');

//Autoload Classes
function __autoload($class_name){
    require_once('libraries/'.$class_name .'.php');
}
```

my page1.php

```
 <?php require('core/init.php'); ?>
     //Get Template & Assign Vars
     $template = new Template('templates/rep/page1.php');
```

if I add an "../" in front of every path. then the page will loads correctly. see below

```
require_once('../config/config.php');
require_once('../helpers/system_helper.php');
require_once('../helpers/format_helper.php');
require_once('../libraries/'.$class_name .'.php');
require('../core/init.php'); 
$template = new Template('../templates/rep/page1.php');
```

but then my index.php will break because index is in the root folder, so the new path is wrong relative to it. I found two question with related issue. I suspect it is related to using `__dir__` to replace ../ but I dont know where to put it.

[PHP include relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)

[Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me personally, I try to make includes relative to the file doing the including, if I'm sure the structure is supposed to be a certain way. For instance, you could make a file at core/loader.php right next to core/init.php ... Then if you assume the relative structure between the loader and the other files would always remain the same, core/loader.php could be something like

```
<?php

// Get the path of whatever folder is holding the core/config/etc folders
$main_dir=RealPath(DirName(__FILE__).'/../');

require("{$main_dir}/config/config.php");
require("{$main_dir}/helpers/system_helper.php");
// etc

?>
```

The point here being that you can now move that set of folders anywhere you want (recommendation: outside public_html), and they should still load, as long as you require'ed the right path to the loader.

Comment: thank you. took me hours reading your post and this one over and over. in the end I used dirname(__DIR__).'/path/to.file' and it worked.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021