# Close mysqli connection in another file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let's assume I have 2 php files
In the first one I have the connection to the database. Since I need it in another php files, I assigned it to a global variable like this.

**setconnection.php**

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'database';

// Create connection
$GLOBALS['connect'] = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($GLOBALS['connect']->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$db_selected=mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS['connect'],'database');
mysqli_set_charset($GLOBALS['connect'],'utf8');
?>
```

And then I have another php file in which I use the connection from the above php file.
It is correct to close the connection like this?

**index.php**

```
include_once "setconnection.php";
$GLOBALS['connect']->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Question! I never see it anywhere in the examples. Closing connection will only save you memory resources. Php is supposed to close non-persistent connection after script execution anyway. However, it may not always be the case. I have had server CPU overloads when legacy code persistently omitted closing connections.
As of now, we keep one connection for several functions, which in essence is the same thing you are doing. Works well for us.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: My problem is that I have a function defined in setconnection.php, and if I close the connection in the end of that file, I can't call the function in other php files...

Comment: @Daniel don't close it then?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know that php closes connections in the end. But i found some advices around here where it says that if you don't close your connection by yourself it can lead to CPU overusage.

Comment: @Daniel don't listen to them

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this is legit. Do not forget to check if the connection is really open or not already closed before closing it.

Answer (score -1):

This is totally legit, as said by [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-%EC%9B%83) on [Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code),

> ... remember that `include()` just inserts code into the currently running script

So, let's say you have a file called **example.php**:

```
function example() {
    echo 'Hello, world!';
}
```

And you include it in **index.php**:

```
include 'example.php';
example();
```

This is the same as having everything in one file:

```
function example() {
    echo 'Hello, world!';
}

example();
```

So there's really not any error in closing the connection in another file which is not the one where you opened the connection.

Comment: I hope nobody would follow your idea

Comment: I'm not very experienced in PHP, but, why not?

Comment: because a connection should be opened once.