# Failed opening '/adodb5/adodb.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmsv2\login.php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
Warning: include(/adodb5/adodb.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmsv2\login.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/adodb5/adodb.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmsv2\login.php on line 3

Warning: include(/config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmsv2\login.php on line 4

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/config/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmsv2\login.php on line 4
```

Comment: i try using include_once. but it not working too..

Comment: Consider including in the question the path for the location  of the files you are trying to include.

Comment: @MartinJoiner i try this.. include "adodb5/adodb.inc.php"; it solve for the adodb5 file.. but for the config file it cant found my config.php. how i can solve this.. the warning message still same..

Comment: Learn about relative paths in PHP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code