# Php: sometimes include a cached file causes error

Tags: php, file, caching

I have a simple cache mechanism:

```
$settings = @include('/var/www/cache/settings.php');
if ($settings === false)
{
    $settings = get it from DB
    file_put_contents('/var/www/cache/settings.php', '<?php return '.var_export($settings, true).';', LOCK_EX);
}
```

it works fine, but as seeing the error logs (I do log the surpressed errors too) it happens often: about 30 times a day. I have more visitors, it doesnt happens often - but it only should happen ONCE! When this file doesnt exists. Still, it happens frequently. What can it be? Its not a facebook-like page to have millions of visitors. Mightbe BOT-s are reading the site too often and multiple calling can cause concurrency?

Edit: no, its not duplicated, you can all see I applied absolute path.

Comment: delete the code which removes the file, then you won't need to keep adding it back :/ why use a file at all when the settings are in the db?

Comment: .... there is no such code

Comment: Log the [current working directory](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) when the miss happens. Swap out the `@include` call with a `file_exists` in the short term for debugging purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)

Comment: @ficuscr nope, you can clearly see that I applied absolute paths

Comment: Absolute to what? It's not a URI. It is relative to the script. Maybe at least try my suggestion?

Comment: ok, I edited to be 101% sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198896/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-john-smith).