# Conflicts including files with relative path

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I'm trying to make includes dynamically in my php script. This is my directory tree:

```
-index.php
-sources/
--hello.php
--bye.php
```

In my `index.php` I make an include of hello.php:

```
include("sources/hello.php");
```

In my `hello.php` I have another include of:

```
include("bye.php");
```

When I access the `index.php` it throws an error saying:

> Message:
>   require_once(bye.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

Is there a way to get it works but without absolutes paths? because the paths can be changeable from one directory to another but keeping the structure:

```
-index.php
-sources/
--hello.php
--bye.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

like this

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/bye.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use **[getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)**?

Contents of `index.php`:

```
include(getcwd() . "/sources/hello.php");
```

Contents of `hello.php`:

```
include(getcwd() . "/sources/bye.php");
```

Comment: See this to know why dirname +__FILE__ is better than getcwd  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184810/difference-between-getcwd-and-dirname-file-which-should-i-use

Answer (score 0):

Since "hello.php" is being included in "index.php", "bye.php" needs to be included in "hello.php" as if it were being included from "index.php".
Like this:

```
include("sources/hello.php");
```

However, if you want to include "hello.php" all over the place and not only in the "index.php" directory, you could set a variable in "hello.php" that gives you the correct path every time.
Like this:

```
$webroot = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/";
include($webroot."sources/bye.php");

OUTPUT -->http://website.com/sources/bye.php
```