# How include in PHP works?

Tags: php

I have file a.php and data folder in one folder. In data folder, I create two files: b.php and c.php.

a.php

```
<?php
   $a = 1;
   include('data/b.php');
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php
 include('data/c.php');
?>
```

c.php

```
<?php
 echo $a;
?>
```

When I run file a.php, result is 1. But I change content of file b.php to `include('c.php')`;
the result of file a.php is also 1.

I think it should show an error because a.php and c.php are not in the same folder.

Comment: Read http://php.net/include - From the folder structure `b.php` and `c.php` look like they are in the same folder, which means that in `b.php` you should `include 'c.php';`.

Comment: OK, but in b.php include('data/c.php'), file a.php show 1.

Comment: Check this line in official doc: `If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.` Word `and` is there for a reason. )

Comment: I'd suggest checking [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2184919/1229023) as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you include a file, even from a subfolder the main "relative" path is still that from first file. Read more about `include` / `require` functions - they just inject script in specified place, does not change including relative path.

Comment: Please explain in more detail!