# Where does the glob() function start searching for file

Tags: php

What is the php's [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function starting point for pattern searching when given arguments like below.

```
$dirs = glob('*');
```

Does it resolve its path like many file handling functions.

Comment: As most things, it's relative to the [*current working directory*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184919/476).

Answer (score 2):

The manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php states:

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the ***libc glob() function***, which is similar to the rules used by common shells.

and pulled from https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Calling-Glob.html and using "libc glob() function" as a starting reference, states:

> **The function glob does globbing using the pattern pattern in the current directory.** It puts the result in a newly allocated vector, and stores the size and address of this vector into *vector-ptr. The argument flags is a combination of bit flags; see Flags for Globbing, for details of the flags.

Side note: The folks at PHP.net may have felt they didn't see the need to repeat those rules. *Why?* I don't know that and would be out of the scope of the question. It would however, have been nice for them to include a hyperlink as a reference (starting) point.

Answer (score -2):

That will be the folder where your script is located.
The function glob does globbing using the requested pattern in the current directory.

Comment: That's a bit too simplistic an answer.

Comment: for this question,it's basic standard usage